# saving environment/running in environment

Tags: lua, operating-system, progress

I'm building an "os" for computercraft turtles, which means I'm bootstrapping on the bios, since I cannot actively override the rom. The problem I'm trying to solve is chunk unloading...  The program will simply stop, and the turtle will turn off.  I want to restore the program to where it was before it unloaded, by saving the current variables, position in program, etc.  How could I get the variables/load the variables?  I can save the global table( _G), but idk how to get the "local" variables without forcing the user to submit all their variables to my program.  I don't want to inconvenience anyone.

http://www.computercraft.info/

https://github.com/KingofGamesYami/Advance-Turtle-Operating-Environment

Comment: Can You use Lua [debug.getlocal()](http://www.lua.org/pil/23.1.1.html) for this matter?

Comment: no, in computercraft you do not have access to debug

Comment: For information as to why we don't have debug, see this thread: http://goo.gl/C53Z0Y